# Permutation of positive real numbers

Tags: inequality, permutations

Consider a set of positive real numbers $\{P_1,P_2,\dots,P_n\}$ and a permutation of this set $\{Q_1,Q_2,\dots,Q_n\}$.

Is it possible to find a permutation such that $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{P_i}{Q_i}<n$$?

We can prove that for $n=2$ the statement is incorrect and assume that for $n=k$ the statement is correct and we should prove for $n=k+1$.

Comment: A permutation such that $\sum \frac{P_i}{Q_i}$ .... what?

Comment: flagged "unclear what you are asking"

Comment: "Is it possible to find a permutation such that sum(Pi/Qi)"... this is half of a question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The geometric mean of those $n$ ratios is $1$. Therefore their arithmetic mean is at least $1$. Therefore their sum is at least $n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guide

Answer (score 0):

If you can prove that the statement is incorrect for $n=2$, then that is all you need to do. The statement is false, period.

Comment: I want to use Induction algorithm and I prove that for n=2 the statement is incorrect but I cannot continue it could you help me?

Comment: @Meh If the statement is untrue for $n=2$, then the statement "this statement is true for all $n$" is false. No induction needed.